# Spring - RestTemplate throwing InvalidMediaTypeException

Tags: java, spring, exception, resttemplate, media-type

I'm working on Spring RestTemplate and i'm getting `InvalidMediaTypeException` after the execution of the below code. When I execute the same service in RestClient app, i'm getting a valid response. Kindly help.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(restUrl,HttpMethod.valueOf(method), new HttpEntity<byte[]>(headers), String.class);
```

Below is the stacktrace.

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid media type "multipart/mixed;boundary=simple boundary;charset=UTF-8": Invalid token character ' ' in token "simple boundary"
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:730)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:305)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:393)
    at com.restclient.helper.RestHelper.getResponse(RestHelper.java:28)
```

Comment: What do you have in the headers?

Comment: content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the header. The method is GET and passing all the parameter as part of URL.

Answer (score 1):

This because missmatch between client content type and server accept content type.
Bassically normal "GET" method the default content type is "text/plain" but is ur case server require something not "text/plain". So u should change contenttype of header when u send  request to your server

Answer (score 0):

Spring parses the `Content-Type` of the response quite strict. As the error message implies, space character is not allowed in the Content-Type field (unless it is quoted). You can read about it in [RFC 2616 section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) or [RFC 2045 section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1). Make sure the server you are calling comply to these rules.

Comment: The space character is part of the response content-type if i'm not wrong. what can i do to avoid this?

Comment: @RajaAsthana Who is running the server application? It is the server side that should be corrected; currently it seems to send syntactically incorrect responses.

Comment: @RajaAsthana It is very possible that other REST clients do a more "lax" (less strict) parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception and stack trace says it all:

On the client-side you have:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response 
    = restTemplate.exchange(
        restUrl,
        HttpMethod.valueOf(method), 
        new HttpEntity<byte[]>(headers), // <-- contains bad "Content-Type" value
        String.class);
```

The `headers` map contains

```
"Content-Type" -> "multipart/mixed;boundary=simple boundary;charset=UTF-8"`
```

When the request hits the server, it tries to parse this header value with `MediaType#parseMediaType(String)`, but the space character is invalid, as noted by the exception message:

> `Invalid token character ' ' in token "simple boundary"`

Next step is to investigate how `headers` is populated.